# Anonymous union in C

Tags: c, structure, unions

I am trying understand anonymous unions for a use case I have. The use-case is to be able to use different prototypes of a given method within a function pointer table. For example in the following code snippet myfunc can have two variants, one that accepts only a string; and one that can accept additional parameters.

Here is my code snippet-

```
typedef struct my_struct
{
    union{
            int (*myfunc)(char*);
            int (*myfuncEx)(char*, int);
    };

}my_struct_t;

int myfunc_imp(char* x)
{
    printf("This is myfunc_imp - %s\n", x);
}

int myfuncEx_imp(char* x, int y)
{
    printf("This is myfuncEx_imp - %s\n", x);
    printf("This is myfuncEx_imp - %d\n", y);
}

int main()
{
    char *string = "Hello World";
    my_struct_t me1, me2;
    me1.myfunc = myfunc_imp;
    me1.myfunc(string);

    me2.myfuncEx = myfuncEx_imp;
    me2.myfuncEx(string, 7);

    static const me3 = {myfuncEx_imp};
    me3.myfuncEx(string, 8);

    return 0;
}
```

Example me1 and me2 seem to provide correct results. 
But example me3. Where I am trying to statically initialize the union within structure, throws this error-

```
warning: initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast
error: request for member `myfuncEx' in something not a structure or union
```

Can someone point out the right way of initializing an anonymous union within the structure.

Edit: I was declaring the struct wrong in a very clearly wrong way, correct way-

```
static const my_struct_t me3 = {myfuncEx_imp};
```

Comment: Try `static const my_struct_t me3 = {myfuncEx_imp};`.

Comment: wow thanks, that was pure dumb from my part. Thanks man.

Comment: There are **no** anonymous `unions` or `struct`s. But there are _anonymous struct or union members_. I.e. the "anonymous" property belongs to the surrounding `struct`/`union`, not to the anonymous `struct` `union`. So, **in  theory** there **could** also be an anonymous `int` member. (just a thought experiment, the standard does not allow this, because you could not reference it,)

Comment: @Olaf, actually, yes, there are "anonymous structures" and "anonymous unions", at least formally.  C2011 6.7.2.1/13 defines those terms, and the standard uses them in several places.  Really, this is the only sensible way to do it, for otherwise it is difficult to talk about or describe the constraints and semantics on such declarations, especially when they are nested.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: Thanks, I was sure they were called "anonymous struct **members**", because that's what there really are. The structs themselves are not (they have a type as any other struct), just the name is omitted, thus "anonymous". But, ok, perhaps that was just too long. Anyway, as given by the standard they are of little use, because you cannot just use a predefined type. I wonder why they stopped halfway.

Comment: @Olaf, well yes, anonymous structures must be members of other structures or of unions, so it is reasonable to call them "anonymous struct [or union] members" to emphasize their context.  But that also de-emphasizes their own type -- not only are they really members, they also really are structures.  Of course, it's moot for most purposes, because the consequence of their anonymity is that you cannot ever refer to them as whole objects.

Comment: @SteveH, the diagnostic you report does not make sense to me, but I *would* expect you to need to spell that initializer `{ .myFuncEx = myfuncEx_imp }`, or possibly `{ { .myFuncEx = myfuncEx_imp } }`, because `myFuncEx_imp` has the wrong type for the first member of the anonymous union.  I don't have a conforming C2011 compiler ready to hand to test it on, though.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: "cannot ever refer to them as whole objects" You are right about the standard. But gcc actually does allow to refer to them by using their type name (requires an extension). Still not sure why W14 did not make them truely useful. As-is, they are near to useless, because you have to define the structure (or uinion) in-place anyway. It is neither fish nor fowl right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into this yesterday. You cannot initialize a union without also specifying the union member. Otherwise it is ambiguous. So,

```
static const my_struct_t me3 = { .myfuncEx = myfuncEx_imp };
```